# how can i add a few seconds buffer in wix ridirect code

Tags: redirect, velo

I am using the following code to point to an external page on wix when someone visits a page on my site -

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 

$w.onReady(function () {
     wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
})
```

my question is, is there a way to cause a 5 second pause before the redirect? i want visitors to be able to see the message " you will be redirected etc etc" as currently it redirects only after a breif moment

Answer (score 0):

As per their DOCs:

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
$w.onReady(() => {
setTimeout(()=>{
if(wixWindow.formFactor === 'Mobile'){
wixLocation.to('ENTER_URL_HERE’) 
} else {
wixLocation.to('ENTER_URL_HERE') 
}
} , 5000)
})
```

https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/redirect-page-after-a-time-delay

Did you search? :)

Answer (score 0):

To add a delay, you can add this line to your code.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 

$w.onReady(function () {
     const milliseconds = 5 * 1000; //Where 5 is the number of seconds, and x1000 converts to MS.
     setTimeout( function(){
         wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
     } , milliseconds);
})
```